# Flask Flatpages not able to load table of contents

Tags: python, flask, flask-flatpages

I made the following small website as an introduction to Flask, and already it doesn't work! It's not able to load the table-of-contents page.

My `app.py`, which is the server is as follows:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from flask_flatpages import FlatPages
from Engine.nerve_net import Nerve_Tree

# Some configuration, ensures:
# 1. Pages are loaded on request.
# 2. File name extension for pages is html.
DEBUG = True
FLATPAGES_AUTO_RELOAD = DEBUG
FLATPAGES_EXTENSION = '.html'

#Instantiate the Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
pages = FlatPages(app)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html') #This returns the main welcome page

@app.route("/contents")
def contents():
    return render_template('contents.html', pages=pages) #This returns the table of contents page

# URL Routing - Flat Pages: Retrieves the page path
@app.route("/<path:path>/")
def page(path):
    page = pages.get_or_404(path)
    return render_template("page.html", page=page)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

My table of contents, the page which displays all files within the `pages` directory is as follows:

```
{% extends "tab.html" %}

{% block content %}
</br>
<h2>TABLE OF CONTENTS</h2>
<ul>
{% for page in pages %}
    <li>
        <a href="{{ url_for("page", page=page.path) }}">{{ page.title }}
    </li>
{% else %}
    <li>No pages so far</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endblock content %}
```

In this example there is only one page in the `pages` directory named `ncs1.html`, which is as follows:

```
title: Hello
published: 2010-12-22

Hello, *World*!

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
```

Pointing the browser to my main welcome page on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/` renders the page successfully. However pointing my browser to the table-of-contents-page on `http://127.0.0.1:5000/contents` gives the following error:

`Could not build url for endpoint 'page' with values ['page']. Did you forget to specify values ['path']?`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: In this line `<a href="{{ url_for("page", page=page.path) }}"` 1. Use single quotes for the inner portion, and 2. I believe your kwarg should be `path`. The corrected line should look like `<a href="{{ url_for('page', path=page.path) }}"` see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

As the author above mentioned, changing the table-of-contents code worked:

```
<a href="{{ url_for('page', path=page.path) }}"
```